# What is this blue half on my screen?

Tags: screen, desktop

In the midst of plugging in my monitor and three-finger swiping up to move Chrome to the second desktop I got this.

[image]

I couldn't access my top bar (with the time and battery) and if I clicked the side that is not blue the blue would switch to the other side.

Unplugged my monitor and it stayed on my laptop screen.

**What did I do?**

Answer (score 2):

Thats a glitch in the [split view feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948).

I would suggest holding down the full-screen button  [image] in the upper-left corner of Chrome. And select a different Window to enter split screen with. Then simply get out of split screen my click the same button on either of the windows. This should reset the feature.

If that doesn't work try running `sudo killall WindowsServer` and enter your password. This is what controls the split view function (no citation, it just appeared this way through minimal testing). This will log you out but hopefully fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'd try resetting the NVRAM to see if that resolves the problem. Before following the steps below, ensure you have no external hardware connected and that you're using the **built-in keyboard**.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Reset the NVRAM on your MBA as follows:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your MBA reboots again (i.e. you hear the startup chime a second time).
4. Let go of the keys and let your MBA reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the Mac fixed it for me on macOS 10.12.6 (16G2136) Sierra on iMac 27-inch Retina 5K (iMac18,3; mid 2017).